# How to replace a element in a nested List in Python

Tags: python

I can locate any listed content. In the example I locate 'q'. I manually mapped its index as `[1][0][1][1]`. Then I replaced it with 'z' and it works. My question is what is the magic to get the index(q) or Object Address(q) when the if() condition get set to True?

```
 import ctypes
    
    lis = [['a', ['b'], 'c'], [['d', ['p', ['q']]], 'e', 'f']]
    idLis = id(lis)
    if 'q' in str(lis):
        idLisContent = ctypes.cast(idLis, ctypes.py_object).value
        print("List Content: = ", idLisContent)
        print("Index 0 = ", idLisContent[0])
        print("Index 1 = ", idLisContent[1])
        qId = id(idLisContent[1][0][1][1])
        print("Index Q = ", ctypes.cast(qId, ctypes.py_object).value)
        idLisContent[1][0][1][1] = 'z'
        print("List Content: = ", idLisContent)
    exit(1)
```

Output:

```
List Content: =  [['a', ['b'], 'c'], [['d', ['p', ['q']]], 'e', 'f']]
Index 0 =  ['a', ['b'], 'c']
Index 1 =  [['d', ['p', ['q']]], 'e', 'f']
Index Q =  ['q']
List Content: =  [['a', ['b'], 'c'], [['d', ['p', 'z']], 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: You can't, because that list does not contain a 'q'.  You can "flatten" the list to get a single list (like `['a','b','c','d','e','p','q','e','f']`) if you need to search it, but the structure you have has to be searched recursively.

Comment: As you can see, search works fine my problem is to get its location index or its object address programmatically. The whole code works ASIS please give it a try.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar There is no search in your code. You manually locate certain element and replace it.

Comment: You didn't replace `'q'` with `'z'`.  You replaced the single-element list containing `'q'` with `'z'`.  There's a difference.

Comment: why on earth re you doing this: `idLisContent = ctypes.cast(idLis, ctypes.py_object).value`??? That is an absurdly, non-portable, implementation-specific way of just getting back `lis`. You already have a variable referencing that list!

Comment: "or Object Address" don't worry about object addresses. You never need to use them. Indeed, they *aren't actually exposed in Python*, only as an implementation detail for `id`, which you should *never rely on*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer a true method to replace the value of a multidimensional array instead of converting it to a string first as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75599730/12715723). Of course, these ways use a recursive function to get the index of the value in the multidimensional array and to replace that with another value using the index.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

def getAllIndex(val, depth):
  if type(val) is str:
    allIndex[val] = deepcopy(depth)
  for i, j in enumerate(val):
    if type(val) is list:
      depth.append(i)
      getAllIndex(j, depth)
      depth.pop()
    
def getValue(val, index):
  if type(val) is str:
    return val
  else:
    return getValue(val[index[0]], index[1:]) 
    
def replaceValue(val, string, index):
  if len(index) == 1:
    val[index[0]] = string
  else:
    replaceValue(val[index[0]], string, index[1:]) 

lis = [['a', ['b'], 'c'], [['d', ['p', ['q']]], 'e', 'f']]

print("List Content: = ", lis)
print("Index 0 = ", lis[0])
print("Index 1 = ", lis[1])

allIndex = {}
getAllIndex(lis, []) # returns {'a': [0, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 0], 'c': [0, 2], 'd': [1, 0, 0], 'p': [1, 0, 1, 0], 'q': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], 'e': [1, 1], 'f': [1, 2]}
indexQ = allIndex['q'] # get index of 'q'

print("Index Q = ", indexQ) # index of 'q' = [1][0][1][1][0] represent as [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
print("Value of",indexQ,"=",getValue(lis, indexQ)) # get value of lis[1][0][1][1][0]

replaceValue(lis, 'z', indexQ) # replace specific value e.g. 'q' => 'z' with index of 'q'

print("List Content: = ", lis)
```

The output will be:

```
List Content: =  [['a', ['b'], 'c'], [['d', ['p', ['q']]], 'e', 'f']]
Index 0 =  ['a', ['b'], 'c']
Index 1 =  [['d', ['p', ['q']]], 'e', 'f']
Index Q =  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
Value of [1, 0, 1, 1, 0] = q
List Content: =  [['a', ['b'], 'c'], [['d', ['p', ['z']]], 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: Yes this was what I was expecting. I am from the C world and think in terms of pointes(*), address(&). Thank you very much for giving the solution I had hoped to get.

Answer (score -1):

Just convert it to string and replace 'q' to 'z'

```
lis = [['a', ['b'], 'c'], [['d', ['p', ['q']]], 'e', 'f']]

str_lis = str(lis).replace('q', 'z');

print  str_lis;
```

Comment: That's a truly terrible way to do something like this.  It doesn't even result in a new list, but in a string.

Comment: Sorry all I wasted all of your time. I am new bee. Thanks Soy Sin for the solution. Should I delete my post? Very sorry again.

Comment: You may want to replace `'q'` rather than `q`, and then you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse back to a list.